# Dynamically Adding values in dropdown

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdowns of State and City. When user selects any state from first dropdown the city reflects in the other dropdown. I have given OTHER option in the city dropdown. So that a user can add its own city for the respective add. Here what is happening the textbox is been hided by default, it is visible when user select OTHER option from the city dropdown. I want the textbox value to be inserted in the dropdown. I tried with below code with the help button but it is not working for me. Please see the code.

```
 protected void ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text == "Other")
    {
        txtOtherCity.Visible = true;
    }
    else {
        txtOtherCity.Visible = false;
    }
}
protected void btnAddDropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (txtOtherCity.Text != "")
        {
            ddllocation1.Items.Insert(0, txtOtherCity.Text);
            txtOtherCity.Text = "";
        }
        string commandtext = "Insert into Career.Job Values('" + txtOtherCity.Text.Trim() + "') where Location='" + ddllocation1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandtext);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);//You Can Haave Messagebox here
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Also, see the html code for the dropdown, textbox and button

```
  <tr>
    <td class="td">Location/City</td>
    <td>
        <asp:dropdownlist cssclass="txtfld-popup" id="ddlLocation" runat="server" autopostback="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:dropdownlist>
        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator cssclass="error_msg" id="reqLocation" controltovalidate="ddlLocation" runat="server" errormessage="Please enter location" initialvalue="--Select--" setfocusonerror="true"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:textbox id="txtOtherCity" runat="server" visible="false" cssclass="txtfld-popup"></asp:textbox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:button id="btnAddDropDown" runat="server" width="63" text="Add" causesvalidation="false" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please help.

Comment: No. Add the additional city to the database (preferably using a stored procedure, not by executing a sql string) - put some error catching code in the stored procedure so it returns a value to indicate success or an error - if it is successful, rebind the city dropdownlist so that it shows the new value.

Comment: How, i want the user to add it in runtime. Or the way you are telling is it possible ?

Comment: I did it on my own. Anyways thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added it like this and it worked.

```
  protected void ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text == "Other")
    {
        txtOtherCity.Visible = true;
    }
    else {
        txtOtherCity.Visible = false;
    }
}
protected void btnAddDropDown_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string city = txtOtherCity.Text.Trim();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
    {
        ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(city, city));
    }
}
```